# Microsoft Word Formatting issue with KDP (How to move titles in the middle of the page?)

Tags: formatting, kindle, microsoft-word

I have my nicely formatted word file to upload to the KDP page for Kindle publishing. When I launch the preview the titles are too high up on the page. This is not a problem for chapter titles, since those need to stay on top, the problem is parts titles—my book is divided into three parts. Each part title occupies a page by itself, so I want them to be somewhere in the middle.
I tried leaving empty lines, changing margins, adding empty titles. Didn't work.

How can I move those titles in the middle?

Just for clarity, this problem presents itself only when launching the KDP Kindle preview. The word file looks perfect, but that's not what readers will get, will they?